# EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION on an optional AFTER validating the optional worked

Tags: swift

I'm very confused. Below I have the following happening.

[image]
As you can see, I check if userOfProfile is not nil before unwrapping. But then I get the following in my console.

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

I also get the following in my stack trace after the error:

```
0x10f67b538 <+72>: leaq   0x4d1e1(%rip), %r8        ; partial apply forwarder for Swift.(_fatalErrorMessage (Swift.StaticString, Swift.StaticString, file : Swift.StaticString, line : Swift.UInt, flags : Swift.UInt32) -> Swift.Never).(closure #2)
0x10f67b53f <+79>: movq   %r12, %rsi
0x10f67b542 <+82>: movq   %r13, %rdx
0x10f67b545 <+85>: movl   -0x2c(%rbp), %ecx
0x10f67b548 <+88>: movq   %rax, %r9
0x10f67b54b <+91>: callq  0x10f54de60               ; function signature specialization <preserving fragile attribute, Arg[1] = [Closure Propagated : reabstraction thunk helper from @callee_owned (@unowned Swift.UnsafeBufferPointer<Swift.UInt8>) -> () to @callee_owned (@unowned Swift.UnsafeBufferPointer<Swift.UInt8>) -> (@out ()), Argument Types : [@callee_owned (@unowned Swift.UnsafeBufferPointer<Swift.UInt8>) -> ()]> of generic specialization <preserving fragile attribute, ()> of Swift.StaticString.withUTF8Buffer <A> ((Swift.UnsafeBufferPointer<Swift.UInt8>) -> A) -> A
```

Any ideas on what to do would be appreciated. I'm pretty confused.

```
var userOfProfile:User?

func loadProfile(_ user: User){
    self.userOfProfile = user

    if self.userOfProfile != nil{
        self.profileView.firstName = self.userOfProfile!.firstName
    }else{
        self.profileView.firstName = ""
    }
...
}


...
//Init for the user object that was passed in. 

let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "User", in: self.managedObjectContext!)
let matchedUser = User(entity: entityDescription!, insertInto: nil)
matchedUser.parseRaw(matchDict)
```

....

```
class User: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var userId: String
    @NSManaged var dbId: String
    @NSManaged var aboutMe: String
    @NSManaged var firstName: String
...
```

The first name property isn't optional. I can even print out the value for firstName by doing `po self.userOfProfile!.firstName` in the console, and it resolves normal..

Look, resolves fine in debugger, crashes on next line. what the heck.

[image]

Let me know if any other code would be helpful.

UPDATE: The issue is the profileView being nil, so setting profileView.firstName is causing a crash.

What I do not understand is why profileView is nil. The code to new up profileView looks like this:

```
//Event that causes all this
let newProfile = ProfileViewController()
newProfile.matchedUserProfile = true
newProfile.matchedReportDelegate = self
newProfile.loadProfile(self.selectedUser!)


//Within ProfileViewController
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    profileView = ProfileView(frame: self.view.frame)
    self.view = profileView
```

In the viewDidLoad for the ProfileViewController, the ProfileView is created. I've followed the stack trace and loadProfile is getting called prior to the viewDidLoad. How do I avoid this? I have many other spots in the code where I do this and it does not crash (this didn't use to crash a couple weeks ago and in our prod version)

Comment: 1. Post actual code, not pictures. 2. Show the declaration for all variables and types involved in the issue.

Comment: You still haven't shown how, `userOfProfile` and `profileView` and its `firstName` are declared.

Comment: Is `self.profileView` `nil` at the time you set one of its property? Is it an implicitly unwrapped optional weak property that is connected through `IBOutlet`?

Comment: Great catch, its something to do with the self.profileView. I tried assigning empty into it and it caused the crash, so the other junk is a red herring and coincidentally looked like it was the problem.

Comment: I can still for some reason print out the value of the profileView.firstName in the debugger just fine, but its not liking when I assign values to it.

Comment: @Unome next time please show your code thoroughly so we don't have to guess. Take a look at rmaddy's comment.

Comment: @OzgurVatansever. I posted this 10 minutes ago and am still actively debugging/updating. I appreciate the help, but not the rudeness. I thought I had posted the relevant code to what I thought the error was, but was completely wrong. The issue is that profileView is newed up in a viewDidLoad, and there is a race condition I believe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if `firstName` property of `userOfPrifile` is optional then it will produce an error at runtime if a value is a nil and you try to forcely unwrap the value.  so, use if let to construct to safely unwrap.

```
if let firstName = self.userOfProfile?.firstName {
  self.profileView.firstName = firstName
} else {
  self.profileView.firstName = ""
}
```

**Updated**

I Guess your `profileView` is nil. please check the `profileView` at runtime.

Comment: Its not optional actually... See my update. I can see the value for this in the debugger and when I print, so it makes 0 sense whats going on. I think that weird error regarding "function signature specialization" has something to do with it.

Comment: check your profileView value. i guess it's nil that's why you are getting the error.

Comment: profileView is nil. Lesson learned, check the assignee for nil in addition to the value, the optional unwrap through me down the wrong path. Happy to know the universe still functions as it should! Stupid me. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: @Unome I would add a precondition to your `viewDidLoad()`: `precondition(self.profileView != nil)`

Comment: I've outlined the root cause of this issue in a separate thread. Since it wasn't 1am and me freaking out I was able to be a little more sane in my writeup. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43947440/referencing-items-initialized-in-viewdidload-safely

Answer (score 1):

You should never unwrap optionals by first checking against nil, then force unwrapping.

Use conditional binding, this does the check and unwrap in one atomic operation.:

```
if let user = self.userOfProfile {
    self.profileView.firstName = user.firstName
}
else {
    self.profileView.firstName = ""
}
```

In a case like this, it's even more succinct to use *optional chaining* and the *nil coalescence operator*:

```
self.profileView.firstName = self.userOfProfile?.firstName ?? ""
```

Answer (score 0):

From your code it seems first name is declared as implicit optional in userProfile as:

```
 var firstName:String!
```

so make sure firstName have value before accessing it other wise it'll crash.

So change it as:

```
   var firstName:String?
```

and access it like this:

```
   if self.userOfProfile != nil{
       self.profileView.firstName =  self.userOfProfile!.firstName ?? ""
   }
```

Comment: You should never compare against nil and then force unwrap.

Comment: Please read updated post. I can see the value in the debugger before it crashes.