# Referencing item's initialized in viewDidLoad safely

Tags: ios, swift, viewdidload

I ran into a bizarre bug earlier this week and wanted to follow up to see how to prevent the root cause of the issue.

Take the following code.

```
//*****************************
//MAINVIEWCONTROLLER CLASS CODE
//*****************************

//Some event happens that triggers me to want to load up TestViewController.
func showViewController(){
    var testController = TestViewController()
    testController.someMethod("Test1")

    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(testController, animated: true)
}

//*****************************
//TESTVIEWCONTROLLER CLASS CODE
//*****************************
testView:TestView!   

override func viewDidLoad(){
    super.viewDidLoad()
    testView = TestView()
    ...
}    

func someMethod(someData:String){
    testView.name = someData         //AppCrashes here because testView might be nil.
    ...
}
```

So `someMethod` is getting fired before `TestViewController` has had the chance to go through and create the `testView`. I'm then getting a cannot unwrap an optional value because `testView` is nil and I'm accessing a property on it.

Whats strange is the application I'm running probably does this exact thing in 6 different places, and 5/6 are working perfectly fine, but 1/6 is now giving me this error. I'm guessing its because of the `viewDidLoad` not being guaranteed to fire immediately or complete before `someMethod` is executed, but why then is this not happening on all 6 of the use cases.

So my main questions are:

1. Why does this crash happen?
2. What is the best practice to avoid it.

Thanks! Thoughtful answers will get up-votes as always! Let me know if any more info would be helpful.

Comment: Where do you call `someMethod`?  Regardless you should conditionally unwrap `testView`. `viewDidLoad` is executed when the view controller's `view` property is referenced for the first time

Comment: Wonder how your code complies. Is testView an optional or an implicit optional ?

Comment: Please post real code that demonstrates what you're asking about. This doesn't compile, and more importantly, isn't even consistent with your description.

Comment: updated the code based on the real code. I wrote the question from memory and missed a few important things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically never run code in the destination controller called from the source controller which involves UI elements. Create a property, set it in the source controller and assign the value to the UI element in `viewDidLoad()` of the destination controller, for example:

```
//*****************************
//MAINVIEWCONTROLLER CLASS CODE
//*****************************

//Some event happens that triggers me to want to load up TestViewController.
func showViewController(){
    var testController = TestViewController()
    testController.someData = "Test1"

    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(testController, animated: true)
}

//*****************************
//TESTVIEWCONTROLLER CLASS CODE
//*****************************
testView:TestView!

var someData = ""   

override func viewDidLoad(){
    super.viewDidLoad()
    testView = TestView()
    testView.name = someData
    ...
}
```

Comment: Awesome, so viewDidLoad will never be called on the init of TestViewController() and I'm safe to set any values I need to prior to viewDidLoad. When does viewDidLoad happen? After pushViewController? on an view.addSubview? +1

Comment: `viewDidLoad` is called right before the view is displayed the first time after `pushViewController`. Add `print` lines to prove it.

Comment: Awesome. Is the same behavior consistent when adding a ViewController manually via its subview? and addChildViewController? Thank you for your help

Comment: I don't know. After initializing the view **controller** `viewDidLoad` is called when the associated **view** has been loaded from the xib or storyboard.

Comment: Okay in that case, I should be safe as long as I set all values before attaching that view as a subview to a loaded view.

Answer (score 1):

viewDidLoad is called when the ViewController completes loading in preparation to be shown, e.g. when a segue takes place or when involved in a present.

As written your code shouldn't even compile since testView is optional, but you have two options. Use optionals (in which case the view may not get the information if not called after viewDidLoad, but it won't crash) or store the passed information and update your view in viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear.

Something you might want to be aware of is [viewIfLoaded](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621360-viewifloaded)

Comment: When does viewDidLoad get called. Is it guaranteed that if I add a property with the value I want to pass, and then call the someMethod from within the viewDidLoad that the value will be set at the time viewDidLoad gets called?

Answer (score 1):

You can force the viewDidLoad method with with:

`var testViewController = TestViewController()
 _ = testViewController.view 
testViewController.someMethod("Test")`

Initializing the ViewController doesn't automatically call viewDidLoad

Comment: Does calling pushViewController() call viewDidLoad?

Comment: Still crashes if I move the testMethod to after pushViewController, so nope.